# How to pass variable into a Blade route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I'm using a `Route::resource` for my project routes.
In my view I would like to pass the `$project->id` into the `project.update` route.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
{{route('project.update', $project->id)}}
```

I also tried:

```
{{route('project.update', [$project->id])}}
```

But still not working due to "404 not found". The url is: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/project/%24project-%3Eid?activation=1`

The route list:

```
GET|HEAD   project/create .......... project.create › ProjectController@create  
GET|HEAD   project/{project} ........... project.show › ProjectController@show  
PUT|PATCH  project/{project} ....... project.update › ProjectController@update  
DELETE     project/{project} ..... project.destroy › ProjectController@destroy  
GET|HEAD   project/{project}/edit ...... project.edit › ProjectController@edit
```

Comment: Show us your route definition, and the resulting output/error of your attempt.

Comment: `{{route('project.update',$project)}}` ???

Comment: Somehow you're generating a link of `project/$project->id?activation=1` - the variables aren't being processed. I'm left wondering if you're actually doing something like `{{route('project.update', '$project->id')}}`

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, just passing `$project` and not just the id:

```
<form action="{{route('project.update',$project)}}">
```